# how do i get a variables ASCII value and use it in a sum

Tags: c, variables, ascii

```
for(i=0;i < strlen();i++;)
{
postnum = argv[i] - k
}
```

i'm trying to write a Caesars encryption program for a course i'm taking, and pretty much i want to have the ASCII value of the i'th character in the string to have a key(k) added to the ASCII value to encrypt the string.
i know to get a chars ASCII number you do 'a' or what ever letter you need but how do i get it from a char variable?

Comment: Characters are implicitly promoted to integers. 99% of the time, this is the ASCII value (but implementations aren't required to use ASCII).

Comment: `'a' + 3` is perfectly legal and gives you 'd'. You can also just assign chars to ints, `int c = 'a'; `

Comment: @thatotherguy, `'a'` is an `int`.

Comment: i know that but is it possible to get a variables ascii number say if i typed: abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just treat each character as an `int` and add `k` to the char:

```
 int i, k = 1;
 char *str = "abc";
 char *ctext = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
 for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
      ctext[i] = str[i] + k;
 }
 ctext[i] = '\0';

 printf("%s\n", ctext);
```

will output:

```
bcd
```

Comment: *Might* be worth mentioning that in this particular case (Caesar cipher), an additional step to "wrap" letters past 'z' back around, but maybe that's for another question.

Comment: @jack please don't copy-paste this code as-is -- it has undefined behavior because of the lack of a terminating NUL byte. You will have to add that too.

Comment: Fixed the null terminator problem.  I felt that it was appropriate to let @jack figure out how to do the wrap around.

Comment: A more efficient way to do the loop would be to use for(i=0; str[i] != 0; i++).  First, because you are calling strlen many times, it's doing the work of finding the length many times, even though the answer is the same each time.  And second, the call to strlen iterates through the string to get the length.. and since you are iterating through the string anyway, you don't need strlen.. you can just check for the null terminator yourself.

Comment: This algorithm is sketchy. If the character set is ASCII, it rolls off the top. If the character set is Windows-1252, it drops into the four or so holes. If the character set is UTF-8, it creates invalid and nonsensical multiple code-unit sequences. In general, there is no `str[i] + k`. It should only be applied to ranges where it is known to work and therefore only to stated character sets and encodings. (Or, 'a'-'z' and 'A'-'Z' since C requires that.)

Answer (score 0):

I did withouth the '' (using C with GCC ver 4.9.2).

I think it's because my array is a string, so is a char type variable.

Code:

```
while(string[i] != '\0'){
    

    string[i] = string[i] + key;

    i++;
}

printf("\n %s", string);
```